# Import module works in terminal but not in IDLE

Tags: python, module, terminal, python-import, python-idle

I am trying to import `pyodbc` module on a windows computer. It works in the terminal, but not the IDLE. The error message in IDLE is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "FilePath/Filename.py", line 3, in <module>
      import pyodbc
  ImportError: No module named pyodbc
```

Comment: Try getting the version of both idle as well as the python run from terminal , you can use - `import sys; print(sys.version)` for that.

Comment: Also look at `sys.path` for both....see any differences?

Answer (score 15):

This typically occurs when multiple versions of python are installed with different paths. You can check to see if you have multiple installations by opening up the IDLE terminal and using

```
import sys
sys.version
sys.path
```

These commands will print the system PATH and version of the current instance of python. Use this in both IDLE and the command line terminal to see where each differ. Once you know which version is the one you want then just remove the other. You could also remove all python instances and then reinstall a clean python environment but then you would have to re-install all of your modules using  pip or easy_install

Comment: On unix or Mac, one should *not* remove the system install of Python, even though one normally used an alternate install.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Why is that?

Comment: Because Mac and at least some linux distributions come with Python scripts tested to work with the system Python.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the OP's error, but I'll add you can get import errors if there is a script with the same name as the package you're trying to import in the same path where you launch IDLE from.

Comment: I was able to uninstall the older version of Python in Windows 11 by going to 'Add or remove programs' and uninstalling the older version. CMD, VScode and Shell were still intact after.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open python in cmd (type `python` and press enter)
2. Import the module in cmd (type `import modulename`)
3. Type `modulename.__file__`
4. You will get the path where the module is stored
5. Copy the corresponding folder
6. In IDLE, `import sys` and typing `sys.executable` to get the paths where it looks for modules to import
7. Paste your modules folder in the path where IDLE looks for modules.

This method worked for me.

Comment: This worked very well for me too! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can `pip show` after install package and know about location where package installed.

After that check in IDLE `sys.path` and if directory with package not in `sys.path` try to add it.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/dm/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
# or another folder that `pip show` about package.
```

Comment: It works for me only if I am running from IDE, if I wanna run the .py file from cmd it says no module found. If I wanna run on cmd line by line it gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

this happen because of multiple python installed (32bit version, 64bit version) or 3v and 2.7v so to solve this problem you have to invoke the `idle` for that specific version like this

`cd` to the `dir` of the version that  the **import work fine in cmd** in that folder type this command below

```
pythonw.exe Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
```

this command will invoke idle for that version 
and the import will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Me too had the same issue while trying to import a module which was successfully imported on terminal and not able to install on IDLE.

[image: ModuleNotFoundError]

How I fixed?
Assuming you know how to execute commands on terminal as well as inside of python interpreter

- Open your Terminal & execute the below commands :

  :~$ python3

  ```
  Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
  [GCC 8.4.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  >>>
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.version
  '3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) \n[GCC 8.4.0]'
  >>> sys.path
  ['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
  '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
  packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
  >>>
  ```

Now import your module inside of your python3 interpreter.

```
  >>> import nester
  >>>
  >>> nester.__file__
  '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nester.py'
  >>>
```

- Open your IDLE and run the below commands and compare them

  ```
  Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 
  64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more 
  information.
  >>> import sys
  >>> sys.version
  '3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit 
  (AMD64)]'
  >>> sys.path
  ```

['','C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs', 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39', 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']

```
  >>> sys.executable
```

'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe'

Now if you compare both outputs from Terminal & IDLE,

- Terminal Module location is different from IDLE
- I was using Ubuntu 18 terminal on windows machine

So I just copied my file to 'C' directory and ensured its file privileges. That's it.

```
  :~$ cp -p /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nester.py /mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/
```

[image: ModuleNotFoundError Fixed]

It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

**I Found the solution. It works for me** 
The problem is your installation directory does not match with the python version directory.
solution is >>>

1. type %localappdata% in your search bar then go to this folder.
2. here select the program folder. then select Programs , Python , Python version , Scripts
3. copy the location of the Scripts folder
4. open command prompt and type cd //yourpath (in my case **cd C:\Users\3C HOUSE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts**)
5. **if you wanna install numpy** , now run **pip install numpy**

Answer (score 0):

When you put your python scripts that have import pandas in the same folder as the site packages like pandas for example and use the same version of python that is used on CMD, it should help run your scripts in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of your code, and that of the module. Copying the module to the path where code is worked for me.
'sys.executable' will give the path where code is stored.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, open command prompt and enter `pip show pyodbc` to get the path of package and copy the path.
then open idle and run these lines

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Match the path from command prompt and the paths mentioned in the list provided by running above lines in IDLE. If the path is not mentioned then run these lines in idle

```
sys.path.append("Enter the copied path of package here")
```

After executing these lines, check again by importing the package that if it works for you.