# python idle 3.6.2, python version 3.6.4 @macOS

Tags: python, python-idle

I ran the same code at IDLE and Jupyter notebook at MacOS.
Then I got the different results.

Jupyter it ran well, but @IDLE it showed: 
No module named 'pyfirmata'

I checked python version at command line, it showed 3.6.4
I checked IDLE, its version is 3.6.2

how can I make the 2 in the same version? Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662063/7547749

Comment: Please carefully read the linked answer and comments.  If `python3` on a command line runs 3.6.4, then `python3 -m idlelib` on a command line will run IDLE with the same 3.6.4.