# How to solve ModuleNotFound Error in IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I first installed Python along with anacondafrom terminal whose version is 3.7.0 and I have launched Jupyter notebook and Spyder as well. Then I installed IDLE whose version is 3.6.6+ and I am currently working in IDLE but then when I tried to import module,it shows the error: No module found. I checked for the path as well for both in IDLE and Terminal which are different.How do I solve this problem?

when I checked the python path,

In terminal,

```
/home/reema/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip:/home/reema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7:/home/reema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload:/home/reema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

In IDLE,

```
['', '/home/reema', '/usr/bin', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I tried appending in IDLE but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should tell ① which OS, distribution you use, ② how you installed Python 3.6 and Idle, ③ how you installed Pyton 3.7 and ④ execute `import sys ; print(sys.path)` in both Pythons and report the results.

Comment: If you want a shoot in the dark, an opinionated shoot in the dark, you simply have installed some modules using 3.6 and the others using 3.7.  `sys.path` tipically references the Python version in the path names it contains.

Comment: I have just edited my question. Hope that makes my problem clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Python Module Works in Terminal but not in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661694/import-python-module-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-idle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to the different interpreters installing modules in different paths, and because the default interpreter at the command prompt is likely 3.7, while the installed Idle uses 3.6

The answer to your problem is to use `pip` to install new modules and invoke  `pip` as follows

```
$ python3.x -m pip install ...
```

This way you know which interpreter is called, and each times the correct version of `pip` is invoked and, each time, the module is installed in the correct path for a given interpreter.

I have to add that, as far as I can tell, the Anaconda distribution does not support Idle.

Comment: so after installing pip, should I re-install my IDLE?

Comment: since I already have installed anaconda package and i cannot install module manually after then,what should I do?

Comment: I checked the pip version and it says 
'pip 18.1 from /home/reema/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)' 
when I tried installing module for python3.6,it says 'no module named pip'
i don't understand the problem. I am a complete newbie and I am having problem understanding it.

Comment: Please pretty please — read my answer. Invoke `pip` using the syntax I've shown _ensures_ that the module is installed for a specific version.  If you do not install for 3.6, it's not available in Idle.  That's all. Trust me.

Comment: Try `python3.6 -m ensurepip` (or just `python` in the 3.6 directory) to install pip to python 3.6.  See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip