# Module can be imported in the terminal, but not IDLE

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Recently, when I use pip to install python modules, I will get an error saying that the module has not been downloaded when I run it in the IDLE. However, when I run the same script in the terminal, it works fine. What is this error and how can I solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import gspread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

Comment: have you tried this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258737/how-to-solve-modulenotfound-error-in-idle  ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have different versions of python installed. 
The version you used pip to install new modules is different from the version you access with IDLE.

Comment: How do I delete the version I don't want?

Comment: depends on which version you want to remove or how that version got installed. if it's MacOS and the version you want to delete is python2.7 you don't want to delete it, it's part of the MacOS.