# Installed Libraries are not being found by my IDE (Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip, python-idle

I'm on mac and I run 2.X on my terminal and 3.X on my IDE if that is important for any reason.

So I wanted to start web-scraping so I wanted to get beatiful soup.

I installed homebrew so I could start installing pip (it wasn't previously installed even though I've been using python for a while for some reason)

I ran `brew install pip3`, then I ran `sudo pip install beatifulsoup4`

To check that beatifulsoup was indeed installed, I entered python on my terminal and I typed `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Next, I typed `BeautifulSoup` and `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>` was returned.

So this means BeautifulSoup is installed and I'm ready to import it on my IDE, right?

Nope. When I typed the exact same line I typed on my terminal (`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`), this was returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/MinecraftMaster/Desktop/help.py", line 1, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

This doesn't make sense. Why can I import a module on my terminal but not on my IDE?

My `sys.path`:

```
Terminal 2.X Sys.Path:
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.21.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.24.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/idna-2.8-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']

Terminal 3.X Path:
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

IDE Sys.Path:
['/Users/HomeFolder/Desktop', '/Users/HomeFolder/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? My first guess is that your IDE is using a different Python module path than the interpreter in your terminal. What's the value of `sys.path` in your terminal and in your IDE?

Comment: @HarryCutts I am using the standard IDLE that I downloaded from python.org. The sys.path is pretty long so I can't paste it into this comment. Here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/P63xY3sW

Comment: Type `python3 -m pip freeze` to make sure that they are installed on your Python 3.x environment.

Comment: @Selcuk This was returned: beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
soupsieve==1.6.2

Comment: So it looks like you have two separate Python 3 installations.

Comment: @Selcuk How would I link the two then?

Comment: There is no such thing as linking them. You should tell IDLE to use the existing one, or install your packages on the other one.

Comment: @Selcuk I would like my IDE to use the 3.X version on my terminal. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661694/import-python-module-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-idle/31662063