# Pygame module not found on Python IDLE

Tags: python, pygame

After I tried installing pygame wheel file using pip install, the installation was succesful, I can import pygame through cmd, but when I try to import it from python IDLE it says that the module Pygame does not exist, what could be the problem here?

Comment: which version of python do you have installed? Which version did you install pygame for? Which version of python is IDLE using? Make sure this all matches.

For example when you run through cmd you could be using pygame for python version 2.7, but IDLE could be using python 3.5+

Comment: Well it seems the cmd is running a different version of python, my IDLE runs python 3.7 whilst the cmd runs the version of 3.6, how can I change this?

Comment: Since they are both running version 3.5++ I don't think this is the problem..

Comment: if you have two pythons then you should have two `IDLE` - I have `idle`, `idle2.7`, `idle3.6`, etc. The same with python: `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.6`, etc. And with pip: `pip`, `pip2`, `pip3`, `pip2.7`, `pip3.6`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try these steps:

answer found somewhere else, so give him credits aswell : [Import module works in terminal but not in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661694/import-module-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-idle)

You can 'pip show' after install package and know about location where package installed.

After that check in IDLE sys.path and if directory with package not in sys.path try to add it

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/dm/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
# or another folder that `pip show` about package.
```