# I have downloaded modules on pip in the command terminal, how do I then use them in an Idle document?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently downloaded my first few modules on the command terminal perfectly. However they are being stored in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages. How can I access that on macOS and use in an idle document?

Answer (score 0):

to start using any module:

```
import <module name>
```

Comment: This is something I have been doing since I started coding. When doing this however it states that it has not been downloaded. However when I use python on the terminal it says already downloaded.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you , check this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099877/11270997