# Raspberry Pi can't find Tesseract eventhough it is installed succesfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-tesseract

I'm trying to get OCR running on my Raspberry Pi but everytime i run the python script it says that the module "pytesseract" is not found. Yet when i access the machine through SSH and run a python3 script in the terminal, it works perfectly. I did put the python script on the Desktop on the Pi though.

**The successful test and the following error**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> import pytesseract
>>> exit()
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd Desktop/
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 OCR.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OCR.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytesseract
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $
```

Comment: Could you please try the debugging suggestion provided in the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31661694/8505509)? Please post the result in the question.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all make sure that you have installed the pytesseract module on the same virtual enviroment that you are trying to run your `import pytesseract` command in.

Comment: I don't think @Zerox has any virtual environment setup in the pi.