# Module can be imported in python but cannot be used from command line

Tags: python, windows, path, package, command-line-interface

This is essentially the opposite of this problem: [Import module works in terminal but not in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661694/import-module-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-idle?newreg=21199bfc6f6f4b0d9b7fd42548e7997b)

If I start a python session and try to import flask, then it works just fine. Despite that, if I just run `flask` from the terminal, it is not recognized.

I have confirmed that the locations which `pip` installs to is on my system path. (I'm on Windows 10 and I typed `$Env:Path` into Powershell to see that, for example, `C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages` is in the system path.)

I am also sure that I did `pip install --user flask` *not* inside a virtual environment. When I run `import flask; print(flask.__file__` I see `C:\Users\Zack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages`)

Any other ideas for what could be going wrong?

Edit: I'm trying to run `flask run`. To check the path `python` uses, I did (in python) `import sys; for i in sys.path: print(i)`

Comment: Did you verify the shebank in the main module is actually using the same python that is on your path?

Comment: @LhasaDad I may be misunderstanding, which shebang are you referring to? There is no shebang I have written myself because so far I've been running python through the CLI

Comment: how are you running the program.  can you add to the post (via edit) the command line you are specifying?   also,  are you using windows cmd shell or powershell?

Comment: The shebang is a unix thing.  you can have the first line of the file have a comment that effectively says what executable to use to run the program.

Answer (score -1):

As Python language based on Python interpreter, before you use Python, it is necessarily to activate the Python env.

Comment: This is a non-specific answer that does not add anything to the question.