# Cannot find installed version of module Pyperclip in Mac OS X

Tags: python, automation

Although I've already downloaded the pyperclip module with the "pip3 install pyperclip" prompt in the default directory of my Terminal in Mac OSX, when I attempt to import it in a Python shell (Spyder or IDLE) I get back an error that the module isn't found. See below:

```py
import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Perhaps I have it downloaded in the incorrect location and it should be in the same directory as my Python? To be honest, I'm not really sure how to do that and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using `pip3` instead of `pip` to install it

Comment: I did use pip3. Sorry I had that wrong in my description.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661694/import-module-works-in-terminal-but-not-in-idle maybe this can help?