# Fixing ModuleNotFoundError for ezgmail

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

As a beginner with Python I've been following the Automate the Boring Stuff with Python book and I'm trying to get the ezgmail module to work by importing it in IDLE. I've already succesfully installed ezgmail via the 'pip install ezgmail' command in command prompt but when I try to import ezgmail in IDLE I get a module not found error:

```
    import ezgmail                   
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
        import ezgmail
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ezgmail'
```

I've used pip to install other modules that I could succesfully import in IDLE so I don't understand what the problem is here. I know this is pretty basic stuff but its frustrating not having the experience to solve it myself. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two different python interpreters. Could you confirm the version you're using currently with `python3 --version`. Another thing you can do is to always create a virtual environment with `virtualenv envname` and then activating the environment using `source envname/bin/activate` before making installation of the libraries.

OR

Another alternative is to just clone the repo of `ezgmail` from Github. Here is the link: https://github.com/asweigart/ezgmail

Once you've cloned it, you can create a project folder and place `ezgmail` in the folder. Then import it using:

`from ezgmail.src import ezgmail`

This is my current folder structure:

```
|--testing
   |-- demo.py
   |-- ezgmail
```

so for me I'm importing `ezgmail` inside `demo.py`

NB: you will need to install `google-api-python-client` and `oauth2client`

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm getting a 'Python was not found' message in command prompt after entering `python3 --version`. Does this have something to do with Python not being in PATH? I selected the 'add to PATH' option when I downloaded Python.

Comment: yes you need to add it to path. you can try this on windows: https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/  and this on mac: https://faun.pub/the-right-way-to-set-up-python-on-your-mac-e923ffe8cf8e

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I added Python to PATH when I installed it. If I type `py` into command prompt I can run Python from the command prompt. So doesn't this mean that it's already been added to PATH? The `py` command tells me I'm running Python version 3.9.6 to answe your earlier question. I've also previously gone into the 'Environment Variables' folder and added:

```C:\Users\Marchy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts```
and
```C:\Users\Marchy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39```

to the PATH variables.

Comment: ok so if the environment is properly configured then it should work. I just tried it now on my pc and it worked, though im running python 3.7.9

Comment: I went back and tried your original command but I ommited the 3 and it worked. So I typed `python --version` and it confirmed I'm using 3.9.6. So can we safely assume I have the PATH variables setup correctly?

Comment: yes it’s correctly set up. maybe downgrading the python version will work because it worked with mine (python 3.7.9)

Comment: Any thoughts on the ezgmail module? I suspect that its just a matter of moving a few files into the correct directory but I'm not sure what all needs to be moved.

Comment: @MarcinLaszkiewicz I've suggested another alternative for you, please check the edit to my previous solution. Hope it works and kindly approve.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964114/16498710

This is what finally worked for me:

"Open python in cmd (type python and press enter)

Import the module in cmd (type import modulename)

Type modulename.**file**

You will get the path where the module is stored

Copy the corresponding folder

In IDLE, import sys and typing sys.executable to get the paths where it looks for modules to import

Paste your module's folder in the path where IDLE looks for modules.

This method worked for me."